# Error while installing pandas. Can anyone tell why?

Tags: python, pandas

```
PS C:\Users\Saksham Kasera\Desktop\data structure> py -m pip install --user folium

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Saksham   Kasera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\Saksham   Kasera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\Users\Saksham  Kasera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\Saksham Kasera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import   DependencyWarning
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

This is dependency issue. Try to remove and reinstall library. Recommended is use different python environment for your installation or Use miniconda for data analysis library and tools. Its take care of lots of dependency issues. Steps are below :

1. Install [miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html).
2. Create environment using command 
   `conda create -n testenv python=2.7`
3. Activate environment always before using it using `activate testenv`
4. Install pandas and all library you want using `conda install pandas`

Enjoy Pandas!